# Meaning of でも in this sentence

Tags: particle-でも

I stumbled upon the following sentence in the J-drama "Mother".

書けない理由でもあるの

A teacher is talking to a student who isn't doing an exercise. I'm aware that the teacher is asking whether there is a reason why the student can't do the exercise. But what is the でも doing there? I would understand a が.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you have a reason *or something* why you can't write it?

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82), the 5th definition, "or something".

Comment: I wasn't aware of that usage of でも. Thank you!